# Google Cloud Storage : java.lang.RuntimeException: Server replied with 400, probably bad request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have created an app which uses the google cloud storage client lib to allow users to upload a file to the cloud. I have created a bucket and added my project account

I have deployed my app and tried to select file to upload it to google cloud, it gives me the following Exception:

```
Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Server replied with 400, probably bad request: Request: PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gemsnps_edunext_1/sample.pdf?upload_id=AEnB2Ur6pjafrkUb_S2BUJKxNClkNfwvaVt7s6rDwnLOm5R6oew0ps0_ilZI1lqP82EChEVqktsj0qA5TcVaVdmfowSpz6AlVg
User-Agent: App Engine GCS Client
Content-Length: 52326
Content-MD5: SB0Bpju4CXK/jcmWTsjiyQ==
Content-Range: bytes 0-52325/52326

52326 bytes of content

Response: 400 with 117 bytes of content
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 117
Vary: Origin
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message></Error>

    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl.close(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:198)
    at com.application.sis.plateform.gae.GaeFileService.saveFile(GaeFileService.java:106)
    at
```

Code

```
            String bucketName = "gemsnps_edunext_1";

            String contentType = item.getContentType();
            GcsFileOptions.Builder fileOptionBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType(contentType).acl("public-read-write");

            if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf") || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")
                    || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx") || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
                    || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ppt") || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".doc")
                    || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docs") || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")
                    || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar")) {
                fileOptionBuilder.contentDisposition("attachment;filename=" + item.getName());
            }

            fileOptionBuilder.cacheControl("no-cache");
            GcsFileOptions gcsFileOptions = fileOptionBuilder.build();


            GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, fileName);
            GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsFilename, gcsFileOptions);

            System.err.println("File Writing");
            writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream)));
            System.err.println("Writer Closing");
            // Now finalize
           writeChannel.close();
```

Error from last line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while trying to write xlsx file to google cloud storage from google app engine.

I changed GCSOptions parameters...

```
GcsFileOptions.Builder fileOptionBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType(contentType).acl("project-private");
```

Note the Parameter passed for ACL.
Hope this helps.